# Custom enum as optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
  public enum Employee
    {
        FT,
        PT,
    }
```

This doesn't work

```
  public ActionResult Index(Employee s = Employee.PT)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = s.ToString();

            return View("MyView");
        }
```

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary
>   contains an invalid entry for parameter 's' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
>   Index(SampleControllerEx.Controllers.Employee)' in
>   'SampleControllerEx.Controllers.HomeController'. The dictionary
>   contains a value of type 'System.Int32', but the parameter requires a
>   value of type 'SampleControllerEx.Controllers.Employee'. Parameter
>   name: parameters

But below one works,

```
public ActionResult Index([DefaultValue(Employee.PT)] Employee s)
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = s.ToString();

            return View("MyView");
        }
```

May I know why 'DefaultValue' only supports custom enum, where optional parameter(4.0) doesn't support it?

Comment: Sounds like your routing is wrong.

Comment: @leppie DefaultValue works with the same routing. why can't .net 4.0 option works properly?

Comment: It would be easier to make the parameter nullable. If you would address the parameter you can use `if ((s ?? Employee.PT) == Employee.PT) { // some code }`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in such way:

```
 public ActionResult Index(int employeeType)
        {
            Employee s = (Employee) employeeType;
            ViewData["Message"] = s.ToString();

            return View("MyView");
        }
```